# How can we create a dynamic element in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

please how Can I do this in ReactJs. is it okay yo manipulate dom directly in react or there is a react way for manipulating dom. I've googled online and still can't find a right information. Thanks

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
x.setAttribute("type", "text");
x.setAttribute("value", "Hello World!");
document.body.appendChild(x);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React has an api called as [`React.createElement`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement), which you can use to create the elements

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      elements: []
    };
  }

  createNew = () =>{
    const newEle = {'element': 'input',  "defaultValue": "Hello World!"}
    this.setState(prevstate=> ({elements: [...prevstate.elements, newEle]}));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.createNew()}>Try it</button>
        {this.state.elements.map(({element, ...rest}) => React.createElement(element, {...rest}))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
class App extends React.Component{
constructor(props){
super(props);
  this.state = {input: []}
  this.addItem = this.addItem.bind(this)
}
  addItem(){
  const input = this.state.input;
    const item = <input type="text" value="Hello World!" />
    this.setState({input : input.concat(item)})
  }
  render(){
  return(
  <div>
    {this.state.input}
    <br/>
    <button onClick={this.addItem}>Try it</button>
    </div>
  )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```